# Android Canvas Screen Resolution problem

Tags: android, canvas, screen-resolution

In my application there is a canvas, when two phones are connected via bluetooth we can share the drawing in real time.

Problem is when phones of different screen size ex: LG Optimus and HTC Incredible S are get connected via bluetooth,
The scaling of the canvas goes haywire only a small part of the canvas in HTC is equivalent to the LGs canvas.

This happens only when i use the following in the manifest file for market compatibility

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"></uses-sdk>
```

If the above is not defined it achieves a proper width size mapping and almost perfect height scaling.

I am not getting why it is happening.
IS there any other way we can map the canvas in such a way that we can scale between different screen sizes varying from phones to tablets.

Comment: I also have same problem , did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```